# how do you call your data from redux into your app?

Tags: mongodb, reactjs, redux

So I came from an angular background where normally I would use ng-repeat in order to get my data to show up on my page but i'm not sure about the exactly method in order to show it on my webpage using react.js and redux. I know that the action and reducer are working so that not a problem. I just want to know how you call the data in order to be put onto the component.

the test data

```
[{"_id":"58c71df9f7e4e47f1fe17eeb","article":"words words","author":"Jason","date":"1/2/2014","title":"my article","__v":0}, more data basically want it to repeat as more data is inserted into the backend]
```

action

```
import axios from "axios";

export const SET_CURRENT_CHARACTER = 'SET_CURRENT_CHARACTER';

export function fetchArticle() {
    return function(dispatch) {
        axios.get("http://localhost:3000/api/fashion")
            .then((response) => {
                dispatch({type: "FETCH_ARTICLES_FULFILLED", payload: response.data})
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                dispatch({type: "FETCH_ARTICLES_REJECTED", payload: err})
            })
    }
}

export function setArticle(_id) {
    return {
        type: SET_CURRENT_CHARACTER,
        _id,
    };
}

export function addArticle(_id,title,date,author,article) {
    return {
        type: 'ADD_ARTICLE',
        payload: {
            _id,
            title,
            date,
            author,
            article,
        },
    }
}

export function updateArticle(id,title,date,author,article) {
    return {
        type: 'UPDATE_ARTICLE',
        payload: {
            _id,
            title,
            date,
            author,
            article,
        },
    }
}

export function deleteArticle(id) {
    return { type: 'DELETE_TWEET', payload: id}
}
```

reducer.js

```
export default function reducer(state={
    articles: [],
    fetching: false,
    fetched: false,
    error: null,
}, action) {

    switch (action.type) {
        case "FETCH_ARTICLES": {
            return {...state, fetching: true}
        }
        case "FETCH_ARTICLES_REJECTED": {
            return {...state, fetching: false, error: action.payload}
        }
        case "FETCH_ARTICLES_FULFILLED": {
            return {
                ...state,
                fetching: false,
                fetched: true,
                articles: action.payload,
            }
        }
        case "ADD_ARTICLE": {
            return {
                ...state,
                articles: [...state.articles, action.payload],
            }
        }
        case "UPDATE_ARTICLE": {
            const {_id,title,date,author,article } = action.payload
            const newTweets = [...state.articles]
            const articleToUpdate = newTweets.findIndex(article => article.id === id)
            newTweets[articleToUpdate] = action.payload;

            return {
                ...state,
                articles: newTweets,
            }
        }
        case "DELETE_ARTICLE": {
            return {
                ...state,
                articles: state.articles.filter(article => article.id !== action.payload),
            }
        }
    }

    return state
}
```

the component that i want the data to show up on in a list.

```
   import React from "react"
import { connect } from "react-redux"
import { Link } from 'react-router';

import { fetchArticle } from '../../actions/fashionActions';


export default class FashionArticle extends React.Component {

this.props.fetchArticle(() => {
   this.setState({
     articleData: data  //Here data is the JSON you received from response
   )}
});

    render() {
        let rows = [];
        this.state.articleData.forEach((item, index) => {
            rows.push(<div className="new-row" key={"row_" + index}>{item.title}</div>);
        });

        return <div>
            <h1>List of Fashion Article</h1>
            <div className="my-article-list">{rows}</div>
        </div>
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have already got the data from response, you can simply bind it to your component state variables in fetch callback and use it in your component DOM. Update your action functions with an extra param to receive callback:

```
export function fetchArticle(cb){
  ...

  if(cb != null){
   cb()
  }
}
```

And in your component, you can retrieve the data by calling the action function either in a lifecycle function such as componentDidMount() or a button event onPress().

And your function could look like this:

```
this.props.fetchArticle(() => {
   this.setState({
     articleData: data  //Here data is the JSON you received from response
   )}
});
```

And then you can bind this.state.articleData in your component like this

```
<h1>{this.state.articleData.title}</h1>
```

If your data contains array, you can loop it through which does the same as 'ng-repeat' in your render():

```
let rows = [];
this.state.articleData.forEach((item, index) => {
  rows.push(<div className="new-row" key={"row_" + index}>{item.title}</div>);
});
```

And you can put it into your DOM now:

```
<div className="my-article-list">{rows}</div>
```

Comment: okay thank you, one last thing that I need to know is for the array loop, where do I place it exactly? Is it  before the  render() or after ?

Comment: Yes, you can put it in render()

Comment: show I tried it and nothing is showing up, what did I do wrong. I edited the component part with the changes and not sure if I did it correctly.

Comment: I assume you have already got the data and can do console.log to see it in your component. Otherwise, you need to make sure you are doing it right to use Redux in your component. Check this official example of redux: (http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/ExampleRedditAPI.html)

Comment: yeah, I have the data. Thanks for the link though